# Is there any C++ codes available to view XPS document?

Tags: c++, wpf, xps

Is there any C/C++ codes available to view XPS document

**EDIT**

Is there any C++ codes available to Edit (add watermark) in XPS document

Answer (score 2):

it depends a bit on what you want to do, but we offer a C++ (for win32 & osx) libray that allows you to render XPS documents. You can also manipulate and draw on XPS files with our SDK.

Take a look here:
[NiXPS SDK info](http://nixps.com/library.html)

You can download a trial here:
[Download NiXPS SDK trial](http://nixps.com/library_apply.php)

Feel free to contact me direct on info@nixps.com

Regards,

Nick 
(disclaimer: I work for NiXPS NV)

Comment: I am looking for opensource or freeware solution.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is possible, but since Internet Explorer can view XPS documents, would just loading a web browser ActiveX into your application work ?